# Get Single True/Flase value from pandas.DataFrame.isin

Tags: python, pandas

I am Using .isin to see if some values exist in the pandas dataframe

```
x = event.isin(['beach','sea'])
```

Then, I am writing an If statement that execute something if there is one or more True values x

but x is a pandas dataframe that look like this:

```
                x0     x1      x2        x3
159615        False   False   False     False
164020        False   False   False     False
165968        False   False   True      False
166484        False   True    False     False
167720        False   False   False     False
```

Comment: what do you want x to return? either `event.isin(['beach','sea']).all(1)` or `event.isin(['beach','sea']).any(1)` ? if not , please elaborate

Comment: Try [`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html): `np.any(event.isin(['beach', 'sea']))`

Comment: yes any Thank you both